# Getting coordinates of point on mouse click using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point, coordinates, xy

I want to get x/y coordinates of a point on mouse click for a point and need to use those coordinates to evaluate other values as per other modules already define.

How can I get x/y coordinates on mouse click in QGIS and print those in PyQGIS?

Comment: You need **QgsMapToolEmitPoint** class to do that (please, see my answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need **QgsMapToolEmitPoint** class to do that. Following code works well for that purpose:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint

def display_point( pointTool ): 

    print '({:.4f}, {:.4f})'.format(pointTool[0], pointTool[1])

# a reference to our map canvas 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 

# this QGIS tool emits as QgsPoint after each click on the map canvas
pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)

pointTool.canvasClicked.connect( display_point )

canvas.setMapTool( pointTool )
```

However, if you prefer a class, following code can also be used:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint

class PrintClickedPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)

    def canvasPressEvent( self, e ):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY())
        print '({:.4f}, {:.4f})'.format(point[0], point[1])

canvas_clicked = PrintClickedPoint( iface.mapCanvas() )
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( canvas_clicked )
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. May be you could add how to unset the listener: `unsetMapTool(canvas_clicked)`

Comment: When you try to use your own maptool in this case, it does not output anything to the console - is there are a reason for that? So lets say you set ```canvas.setMapTool( pointTool )``` - it outputs noting to the console, yet the crosshair shows on the mapcanvas. Thanks @xunilk

Comment: I'm adding these lines to a function inside a plugin, and nothing happens... not even the crosshair. Error log is "NoneType: None" (I can keep working with the plugin, just the focus shifts from the plugin dialog to QGIS, that's all)...