# QGIS 3 Get coordinates from mouse click

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqt5

I am working on a small QGIS Python plugin and want to get the X/Y coordinates from a user click on the canvas. I have a small UI called from button in a toolbar. After filling the UI with information I would like to get the XY coordinates. I am using QGIS 3 with Python 3 and QT5.

I tried to use the steps from 
[How to get co ordinates of points on mouse click in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253733/how-to-get-co-ordinates-of-points-on-mouse-click-in-pyqgis)
but when running it jumps right to the end without calling the display_point function and there is no reaction to mouse clicks.
Are there any changes to the current QGIS version?

My code, which is inside the plugin class and called by a button from the toolbar without UI.

```
def run2(self):
    # a reference to our map canvas 
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 

    # this QGIS tool emits as QgsPoint after each click on the map canvas
    pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)
    # Checkpoint
    print("S 1")
    pointTool.canvasClicked.connect( self.display_point )
    canvas.setMapTool( pointTool )
    # Checkpoint
    print("S 3")

def display_point( pointTool ): 

    print('({:.4f}, {:.4f})'.format(pointTool[0], pointTool[1]))
    # Checkpoint
    print("S 2")
```

Comment: I'll try the class suggestion from : How to get co ordinates of points on mouse click in PyQGIS above in a short plug in to see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a plugin (displayed "Always On Top"), with PyQGIS 3, to avoid it jumps right to the end without calling the display_point function you need following changes in your code:

```
.
.
.
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
.
.
.
    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.
.
.
.
        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = WhereAmIDialog()
        self.dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
.
.
.
    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
.
.
.       
        result = self.pointTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.display_point)
.
.
.
    def display_point(self, point, button):  
        # report map coordinates from a canvas click
        coords = "{}, {}".format(point.x(), point.y())
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(coords)) 
        self.dlg.show()
.
.
.
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        # make our clickTool the tool that we'll use for now    
        self.canvas.setMapTool(self.pointTool)
.
.
.
```

It works; as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The  "point.x()" is the important change as "pointTool[0]" results in an index error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close: :)

I did copy and paste the code from the link to xunilk's answer.   It worked fine in the Plugins/python console.

If you are using the plugin you may have to include 'self' in the method definition.  Also,  the pointTool.canvasClicked.connect( self.display_point ) has to be somewhere that is "ran" by the main method.   Does "S 1" ever get printed?

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint

def display_point( pointTool ): 

    print ('{:.4f}, {:.4f})'.format(pointTool[0], pointTool[1]))

# a reference to our map canvas 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 

# this QGIS tool emits as QgsPoint after each click on the map canvas
pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)

pointTool.canvasClicked.connect( display_point )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try your solution. "S 1" and "S 3" are shown, "S 3" not.