# How to connect a QgsMaptool with a widget pushButton

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqt, qgsmapcanvas

I've write this QgsMaptool above and it works great in python console

```py
imports...

class obsCreator(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.layer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
        self.x = float
        self.y = float

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        point = self.toLayerCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY())
        self.x = point[0]
        self.y = point[1]

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        feats = []
        pr = self.layer.dataProvider()
        fields = self.layer.fields()
        fet = QgsFeature
        geom = QgsGeometry().fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(self.x, self.y))
        fet.setgeometry(geom)
        feats.append(fet)
        fet.setAttributes([1, 'test'])

        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.canvas.unsetMapTool(self)
        else:
            pr.addFeatures(feats)
            self.layer.triggerRepaint()
        pr.addFeatures(feats)
        self.layer.triggerRepaint()
```

but, I want to connect it with a pushButton in my dockwidget:

```py
    def run(self):
        if not self.pluginIsActive:
            self.pluginIsActive = True

            if self.dockwidget == None:
                self.dockwidget = revEnvDockWidget()

            self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)

            # show the dockwidget
            self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
            self.dockwidget.show()

            # Clear comboBox (useful so we don't create duplicate items in list)
            self.dockwidget.obsComboBox.clear()

            # Add all items in list to comboBox
            self.dockwidget.obsComboBox.addItems(Handler.obsListCombo(self))

            canvas_clicked = obsCreator(iface.mapCanvas())
            self.dockwidget.hookPushButton.clicked.connect(iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(canvas_clicked))
```

and I get this error:

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "E:\_Code\QGIS\rev_env\rev_env.py", line 268, in run
              self.dockwidget.hookPushButton.clicked.connect(iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(canvas_clicked))
             TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

I`ve based my code in this question: [How to get co ordinates of points on mouse click in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253733/how-to-get-co-ordinates-of-points-on-mouse-click-in-pyqgis).
Am I missing somethig?

Comment: The clicked.connect() signal/  slot expects a function argument. You can pass a lambda function. Try changing last 2 lines: `self.canvas_clicked = obsCreator(self.iface.mapCanvas())` `self.dockwidget.hookPushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.canvas_clicked))`       Does that work?

Comment: Thanks @BenW, it works perfectly, with you want to answer the question I'll vote for best answer.

Comment: Great- glad to hear it works. I will post an answer tomorrow.  Otherwise, I don't mind at all if you want to answer your own  question based on my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @BenW comment I use a lambda function to pass a dockwidget parameter and it works perfectly.

```py
 def run(self):
        if not self.pluginIsActive:
            self.pluginIsActive = True

            if self.dockwidget == None:
                self.dockwidget = revEnvDockWidget()

            self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)

            # show the dockwidget
            self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
            self.dockwidget.show()

            # Clear comboBox (useful so we don't create duplicate items in list)
            self.dockwidget.obsComboBox.clear()

            # Add all items in list to comboBox
            self.dockwidget.obsComboBox.addItems(Handler.obsListCombo(self))

            self.canvas_clicked = HookCreator(self.iface.mapCanvas(), self.dockwidget)
            self.dockwidget.hookPushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.canvas_clicked))
```