# How to export Coordinates when clicking on Points?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, export, coordinates, table

Assumed I click around on a map, while I need to export the coordinates of the points where I have clicked into a simple text file. In best case, writing into the text file should be performed automatically.

**Example:**

1. Mouse click 1 will write `52.516417, 13.378361` into the table
2. Moving the mouse
3. Mouse click 2 will write `52.556877, 14.358861` into the table
4. Moving the mouse
5. Mouse click 3 will write `current coordinates` into the table

**Background:**

OpenStreetMap is using polygon lines to visualize streets. I want to create a custom route along specific streets and hereby export the coordinates of the points where I have clicked.

Is this possible in OpenStreetMap or QGIS?

---

The approach of [eurojam](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411459/105181) is great! Unfortunately, it does not work on my very old version of QGIS as I receive the following error:

Is this caused due to old python or due to old QGIS? Would it be possible to refactore the python code so it works on QGIS 2.14.11 as well?

[image]

Comment: It's possible to load the openstreetmap basemap into QGIS.  Then you can create a new vector layer (lines).  You can then create lines by tracing routes, which you can export to a text file, or you can explode the lines to points and export the points to a text file.

Comment: As it was pointed out by @jbalk, you can  load the openstreetmap basemap into QGIS and to code in Python, as in following link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253733/how-to-get-co-ordinates-of-points-on-mouse-click-in-pyqgis , for creating a custom route along specific streets and hereby export the coordinates of the points where you have clicked (to the python console, to a Qt display object or to a text file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one simple solution would be to use Layeractions and log the clicked coordinates within the Log Messages from QGIS:

1. Open the Properties of your OSM Street layer and go to the Actions tab
2. Press Add
3. Define a Python Action
4. Enter the Code

The Code fragment:

```
QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "[% @click_x %] ,[% @click_y %]", tag='Coordinates', level=Qgis.Info)
```

QGIS2.14 you can try:

```
QgsMessageLog.logMessage( "[% @click_x %] ,[% @click_y %]")
```

[image]

1. Choose the Action from the Toolbar and click in on the Roadlayer
2. Open the message log
3. In the message logs there will be a new tab: coordinates where the clicked positions will be listet. you can copy and paste them from there...

[image]

Comment: this is really a smart solution!

Comment: Thank you very much for this great approach! Unfortunately I am using a very old version of QGIS (2.1.4.11) which is probably the reason why your Python-code does not work as expected (see error screenshot in my question post). Would it be possible to get it work with older versions as well?

Comment: @Dave: I edited my answer above.