# Using coordinates from mouse click for QgsPointXY when creating point using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point, geometry, fields-attributes, coordinates

I can not figure out how to input the coordinates through a mouse click instead of the code below. I am trying to create a temporary layer of a point from a mouse click. Everything seems to work except for that I can not figure the coordinates out.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "POI", "memory")    
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.String)])
vl.updateFields() 
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(10,10)))
f.setAttributes(["1"])

pr.addFeature(f)
vl.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: This can help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253733/getting-coordinates-of-point-on-mouse-click-using-pyqgis/253738#253738

Comment: Thank you! Even using this to help though, I can not find out how to add the selected point from this tool to a field, or even just regular lat and long coordinates into this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining lines in this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253733/getting-coordinates-of-point-on-mouse-click-using-pyqgis/253738#253738) and your code, it looks as follows:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

def display_point( pointTool ): 

    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "POI", "memory")    
    pr = vl.dataProvider()
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField("ID", QVariant.String)])
    vl.updateFields() 
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(pointTool[0],pointTool[1])))
    f.setAttributes(["1"])

    pr.addFeature(f)
    vl.updateExtents() 
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

# a reference to our map canvas 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 

# this QGIS tool emits as QgsPoint after each click on the map canvas
pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)

pointTool.canvasClicked.connect( display_point )

canvas.setMapTool( pointTool )
```

After running it in Python Console of QGIS 3, it can be observed in following image, after 10 mouse clicks, there were produced 10 point layers as expected.

[image]